# No Flagged email folder on iCloud browser?

Tags: icloud, email

Is it just me, or is there no Flagged folder on the browser version of the iCloud client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of your email list click the "Filter" button.  The default tends to be "Unread". Click on "Unread" and a menu pops up where you can select "Flagged"
[image: Popup Menu]

Comment: Yes - the web app for iCloud mail has caught up to this feature! Great answer

Comment: brilliant! thank you so much https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/335768/nigel

Answer (score 2):

There is no Flagged mailbox in the Mail "app" of iCloud.com. It also does not appear after flagging a message.

At present, you can:

- use Mail.app (or another computer mail client)
- use an iOS device to see the flagged mailbox that was introduced in iOS 6 for iOS devices.
- ask Apple to add this to iCloud at http://apple.com/feedback